# While updating the Application all local files are deleted in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my application I have saved videos and photos in document directory and photos and videos url path store in sqlite. While updating (Upgrading) the iPhone Application all document directory photos and videos are deleted. But other parameters stored in sqlite not deleted. How to I retain the files while updating the app?

-(BOOL)saveImageToDocumentDirectory:(UIImage*)imgToBeSaved 
{
    BOOL flag = NO;

```
strPhotourl=nil;

NSData* imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imgToBeSaved, 1.0);
```

// NSData *imgData1=UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgToBeSaved);

```
// Create a new UUID
CFUUIDRef uuidObj = CFUUIDCreate(nil);

// Get the string representation of the UUID
NSString *strImageName = (__bridge NSString*)CFUUIDCreateString(nil, uuidObj);

CFRelease(uuidObj);

//Call Function to save image to document directory

NSArray* arrAllDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString* strDocumentDirectory = [arrAllDirectories objectAtIndex:0];

NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSString *fullPath = [strDocumentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[strImageName stringByAppendingString:@".png"]];

strPhotourl=fullPath ;// strPhotourl store in sqlite db table two show images in  tableview

//    NSLog(@"Image in strphotolocation==%@",imagePath);
```

// NSLog(@"fullpath---%@",fullPath);

```
if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fullPath])
    flag =     [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imgData attributes:nil];
else
    flag = NO;
return flag;
```

}

Comment: That isn't supposed to happen.

Comment: How did you determine that files are deleted? And where exactly your files stored? There are some special directories in iOS for different purposes.

Comment: @trojanfoe, I am inserting some data in sqlite db like store images in document directory and store url in sqlite db table, So when i update application version then images not show using images url from document directory

Comment: During an app upgrade none of the document files are supposed to be touched, only the app bundle.

Comment: Suppose photos added in document directory and url stored in old sqlite database table then how to show these images in new or updated iphone app?

Comment: Please, show us some code: how you're saving images, how you're storing URLs in DB and how you're getting them back. As @trojanfoe mentioned, no directories affected while standard app updating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't save the entire path into sqlite,just save the file name which you are stored in local so while fetching, get the current directory path and append with fileName from sqlite. This will solve when you upgrading your app also.

Comment: Or at least the filename *relative* to some known (but dynamically determined) directory.

Comment: @wesley very very thanks a lot my issues is solve using ur suggestion

Answer (score 8):

The reason is not because any files were deleted but because the folder an iOS app resides in **does change** during an upgrade. The folder your app is stored in is named using a GUID, and this may change on an upgrade.

You should not store the full URL/PATH to any files in your Documents folder, as this is not guaranteed to remain after an upgrade.

> **Files Saved During App Updates**
>
> When a user downloads an app update,
> iTunes installs the update in a new app directory. It then moves the
> user’s data files from the old installation over to the new app
> directory before deleting the old installation. Files in the following
> directories are guaranteed to be preserved during the update process:
>
> - Application_Home/Documents
> - Application_Home/Library
>
> Although files
> in other user directories may also be moved over, you should not rely
> on them being present after an update.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html

If you already have the app deployed on users phones, then what you could do is when you read the url from sqlite, remove the leading path (eg: /var/mobile/Applications/---guid---/Documents) and then re-save the entry before using it.

Comment: By the way, I noticed that with iOS 8 the folder structure changed as well. So Don't rely on the structure under the GUID either. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2406/_index.html